# How to set ringer modes on Android 7?

Tags: audio, 7.0-nougat

In Android 7, where are the various ringer modes? They seem to have disappeared or been hidden. Before, in previous versions, it had 3 modes: Silent, Vibrate, Normal. Where have this icon and mode gone?